# using annotations in spring pointcut

Tags: java, annotations, aop, spring-aop, pointcut

I am using annotation to indicate that an advice needs to be applied to the method.

I have the two methods in an interface called `IMaintenanceDAOSupport`

```
@AuditLogging
void insert(M domainobject, IntResponse response, String statementName);

@AuditLogging
int delete(M domainobject, IntResponse response, String statementName);
```

How do we configure the xml for the aspect to be applied?

At present I have

```xml
<aop:config>
  <aop:aspect  ref="auditAOP">
    <aop:pointcut id="im-insert"  
                  expression="within(IMaintenanceDAOSupport)and execution(@annotation(AuditLogging))"/>
    <aop:after method="afterInsertUpdateOrDelete" pointcut-ref="im-insert"/>
  </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

It is giving a compilation error; Do you see any mistake in the configuration ?

Comment: "giving a compilation error" what error do you see ?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'name pattern' at character position 139

Answer (score 0):

You should combine point cut expresstions using **"&&"** rather than "and".

Pointcut expressions can be combined using '&&', '||' and '!'.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Tried your suggestion, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

`@annotation` does not require the execution() block. Try:

```
within(IMaintenanceDAOSupport) && @annotation(AuditLogging)
```